# Creating a custom MVC routing based on Controller Namespace name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, attributerouting

I have system with several Areas. Inside then, I created a folder structure for my controllers (following the menu structure), like that:

```
- Areas 
  - Area1 
    - Controllers
      - Folder1
        - Folder2 
          - Controller1
          - Controller2
        - Folder3
          - Controller3
 ...
```

Ok, so far so good... With default routing I got :

```
mysite.com/Area1/Controller1/Action
mysite.com/Area1/Controller3/Action
```

What I want to achieve is something like that :

```
mysite.com/Area1/Folder1/Folder2/Controller1/Action
mysite.com/Area1/Folder1/Folder3/Controller3/Action
```

Or (slug):

```
mysite.com/Area1/Folder1-Folder2/Controller1/Action
mysite.com/Area1/Folder1-Folder3/Controller3/Action
```

I can use the namespace controller name to create that slug, if that kind of thinking is valid (Controller 1 namespace):

```
namespace MyProjet.Areas.Area1.Controllers.Folder1.Folder2
```

How can I do that?
Maybe using something like AttributeRouting?

Thanks

Comment: http://attributerouting.net/#route-prefixes

Comment: maybe you can go for custom routes, parsing the url and returning the desired route data: http://www.devcurry.com/2013/05/customizing-routes-in-aspnet-mvc-custom.html

Comment: If you're feeling adventuruos you can try routing by convention http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2013/04/08/AspNet-Mvc-Routing-By-Convention.aspx